# How to import a type incuding its package name

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm using last version of openapi-generator-maven-plugin (6.0.1)

In order to handle some binary data properly I need to use `typeMappings` configuration as described here : https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md

So I configure my pom as following :

```
<configuration>
    <typeMappings>
        <typeMapping>string+binary=org.springframework.core.io.Resource</typeMapping>
    </typeMappings>
</configuration>
```

But the code-generator understand it as a `OrgSpringframeworkCoreIoResource` class. **How can I tell it not to camel case my parameter?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally undertand the problem : it's a 2 step configuration.

```
<!-- First we map the OpenAPI type to a keyword -->
<typeMappings>
    <typeMapping>string+binary=Resource</typeMapping>
</typeMappings>

<!-- Then we attach the keyword to an existing type -->
<importMappings>Resource=org.springframework.core.io.Resource</importMappings>
```

That's way it works!

Comment: Okay, great that it works! I just wondering if you are generating client or server side code. I guess this would be the client side. Which generatorName and library are you using?

Comment: @schoener yes it's client side. I'm using `spring` generator name and `spring-boot` library. In the end I use the following mapping to handle binary stream: `<importMappings>DataBuffer=org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer</importMappings>`. It's much more integrated with WebClient API